# Replace a character used as a separator PySpark CSV

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have a CSV file that I read with PySpark in Databricks with code:

```
df =spark.read.options(delimiter='|',header=True ,multiLine=True).schema(schema).csv('/mnt/file.csv')
```

I'm reading multiple files sequentially all CSV with separator `|`.

The problem is that a field in my file has multiple | and this is obviously making all the dataframe wrong (I can't even save it because a Timestamp field is being filled with a String field).

I don't know in which file this could happen, in which field and I don't have any quote (for example `"` ) to be used. I can't even modify it in the file as I have more than 1000 files and some of them are more than 10 GB.

Can I find a workaround to solve thhis problem?

I tried with this:

```
df =spark.read.options(delimiter=',',header=True, multiLine=True, inferSchema=True).csv('/mnt/file.csv')
df.withColumn('header|in|one|row', regexp_replace('header|in|one|row', 'text||||text2', 'text text2'))
```

But it does not work ('text||||text2' it's an example that the error let me see)

Answer (score 0):

You can define the `schema` of the file and read the file with `header True` and pass the schema.

In this case spark will read the header and add the schema to the dataframe.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

sch = StructType([
    StructField("A", IntegerType()),
    StructField("B", DoubleType()),
    StructField("C", StringType())
])
df =spark.read.options(schema = sch, delimiter=',',header=True, multiLine=True, inferSchema=True).csv('/mnt/file.csv')
```

Comment: I have a defined schema, but if I have in my file Header ```A|B|C``` and a row  ```text|text|||2|text3```  it shifts the content of my row in the wrong column, because my delimiter is "|"

Answer (score 0):

- I have a file that has `|` delimiter and one of the field's value has consecutive `|` characters. I have read the file using text format and the following is the dataframe result:

```
df = spark.read.text('dbfs:/FileStore/sample1__1_.csv')
df.show(truncate=False)
```

[image]

- Now using the ``regex_replace`function, I was able to replace any trace of multiple`|` characters. The following is the code that I used:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df1 = df.withColumn('value', regexp_replace('value', r'\|{2,}', ' '))
df1.show(truncate=False)
```

[image]

- I have then written it back in text format. But when I read it, I read it using csv format with delimiter as `|` and get the appropriate results:

```
df =spark.read.options(delimiter='|',header=True, multiLine=True, inferSchema=True).csv('/FileStore/final')
df.show(truncate=False)
```

[image]

**NOTE:**

- This works only if there are multiple `|` characters in the field's value. If there is just one random `|` in the value, then it cannot be differentiated from the delimiter.
- Also, this works only if the field's value does not with multiple `|` characters. If this is the case, then these additional characters are mixed with the actual column delimiter and thus does not solve the issue. This is one possible way to do resolve the particular case.

Comment: This could be good, only problem is that if a field Is empty it will change also that one, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, the data is malformed and needs to be checked. Its is hard to do these operations as there can be many factors as such